# How to feed outdoor cats when you're away for a month

Tags: cats, feeding, outdoor

I have an outdoor cat that my neighbors refuse to feed. Now I have to be absent for one month.

How can I feed my cat during my absence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of automatic cat feeders available. Some are fairly high tech, and if you spend enough money you could conceivably supply 30 days of food for the cat.

The problem is that it is outdoor cat, most of the automatic cat feeders I found are not cat specific, there are a few, but it would get very expensive and problematic to ensure that only "your" cat got the food.

Neighbor cats, racoons, mice, rats, etc. Are all going to want some of the cat food.

30 Days is a long time to leave an animal without direct supervision, even if it is only casual supervision now.

At the very least you would need to hire someone to come do the feeding and provide whatever assistance the cat may need. This might be daily or every few days.  Alternately you could bring the cat to a cat boarding facility, they would keep it indoors and take care of feed, water and cleanup.

Lastly if you are not able to adequately arrange for care of the cat in your absence you should, take it to a local shelter and ask them to find a new home for it.

Answer (score 2):

Any friends or family that could help? I’m sure you’ve already tried that but i can’t think of any other way. The cat will need water and food daily so if you can’t get anyone to watch him/her, maybe a kennel? Shame that your neighbours won’t help out

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I still want to respond to others that might be searching for this kind of information. You can ask (post) on craigslist or neighborhoods. I am part of a small unknown secret society of people that make our rounds to areas of stray cats in our neighborhood. (feeding & providing water). We do it daily and have run into each other. Our efforts overlap but it takes the total burden off of any one person. Ensuring that no matter what the cats will receive sustenance. So since I'm bringing this up, just know that "we" exist, basically everywhere. Also you could hire a person through a pet sitting site or even a responsible college student. Just post it on the cork board and someone wanting a side gig can respond. Also someone on task rabbit would probably do it as well.